# Most efficient way to create a Scala Map from a file of strings?

Tags: string, scala, dictionary

Now, I am trying to create a `Map[String, String]` from the csv file where the word is the **Key***, and the pronunciation is the **Value**. I have managed to do it myself using the code below.

```
def mapFile(filename: String): Map[String, String] = {
    var content: String = ""
    val file: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile(filename)

    for (line <- file.getLines()) {
      if (!line.contains("//")) {
        content = content + line + "//"
      }
    }

    content.split("//").map(_.split("  ")).map(arr => arr(0) -> arr(1)).toMap
}
```

So file reads the text file, and for every line in the the text file that is not `//`, it creates a string and then splits the string into key-value, key being split by `" "` and value being split by `"//"``.

However, it is too slow.
Is there a more efficient way i can create the map without it taking 5 minutes?

Comment: `if (ok == false)` is the same thing as `if (!line.contains(";;;"))`. Choose the 2nd one, it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your main problem is that you are reading all your file into a **String** to reprocess it after. Which means, you don't only allocate twice of required memory, but that you *process* your file twice too.

The first improvement you may made to your code is to do everything in just one *iteration*.

```
import scala.io.Source

def mapFile(filename: String): Map[String, String] =
  (for {
    line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
    if (line.nonEmpty && !line.startsWith(";;;"))
    Array(word, pronunciation) = line.split("  ")
  } yield word -> pronunciation).toMap
```

The above code is equivalent *(and will be desugared to something very similar)* to this:

```
import scala.io.Source

def mapFile(filename: String): Map[String, String] =
  Source
    .fromFile(filename)
    .getLines
    .filter(line => line.nonEmpty && !line.startsWith(";;;"))
    .map(line => line.split("  "))
    .map { case Array(word, pronunciation) => word -> pronunciation }
    .toMap
```

---

Additionally, if the input file is too big, you may give a look to [**FS2**](https://fs2.io/), or [**Akka-Streams**](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/), or any other kind of *streaming* to process the file by chunks.

Comment: ur a genius, this worked amazing, went from 5 minutes to 5 seconds. thank you, what exactly is happening during after Array?

Comment: @fuckshy If you mean `Array(word, pronunciations @ _*)`, it is just **pattern matching**, it means _(in roughly human words)_: We know the output of split is an Array, and we are sure there will always be at least two elements _(assuming all words in your file will have at least one syllabus, which kinda makes sense)_ so, we will take the first one out and give it the name `word`, and the rest will be take out on as a Sequence which we will call `pronunciations`, hope it is clearer now. [**Reference**](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-pattern-matching-scala-match-case-expressions).

Comment: @user11039395 edited the answer: Fixed the error and added the _"desugared"_ form of the code.